# Use SharePoint 2010 workflow to add permissions to a document library

Tags: sharepoint-2010, moodle, sharepoint-workflow, scorm

I'm trying to create a register, in a way, so that users (who initially have read permissions) on a SharePoint site, can add themselves to a group which has contribute permissions to a document library. This is something similar to what Moodle can do, where users can enrol themselves on a course.

My thinking is that I'd setup a list that allows all users to have contribute permissions. A user would then add a very basic list item which would start a workflow. The workflow would add the said user to a group that already has contribute permissions to a document library.

If it helps, here's the reason:
We have a lot of students accessing our SharePoint site (well over 2000), and all students are under a general AD group. To use the SharePoint Learning Kit (and therefore make use of SCORM content), there has to be a SharePoint group with specific rights, and that group should, ideally, contain individual users rather than AD groups (depending on the size of the AD group). Unfortunately, there isn't a way to get our learner record system to expose a field which SharePoint could 'see' which is why all students are under a general AD group. Because there are so many students (some with similar names), it would be a hard task to get lecturers to filter through each student to add them manually to the SLK group that's needed. Which is where this idea comes in. A student could enrol themselves into the SLK group and get access to the SLK material.

And breathe.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of possible ways to do this. For example you can [create custom timer job](http://www.andrewconnell.com/Creating-Custom-SharePoint-Timer-Jobs) which will run every 15 minutes and synchronize sharepoint group with list you mentioned. If you want to stick to workflow way you can [create custom workflow action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee231574.aspx) which will add user to sharepoint group and then create workflow which uses this activity using sharepoint designer.